# Ajax in UserControl

Tags: asp.net, ajax, user-controls

i have a signup page and i want to check username exists or not with ajax

```
 <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Simple.ascx.cs" Inherits="UserControls_Simple" %>
<div style="direction:rtl;">
<table style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:12px;width:200px;">
<tr>
<td>نام کاربری:</td>
<td><asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text="Username Already Exists" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
</td>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>کلمه عبور</td>
<td><asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

i want to show label if user exists

how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Ajax to check if a user exists in your DB via a User Control (or whatever method you are using) is the same method you would use in a Web Page.

What kind of Ajax do you want to use?  MS Ajax, jQuery, what?

Regardless, you will need to [Call Web Services from Client Script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515101.aspx) to perform an AJAX request.